# Fourier transform of a Bessel function multiplied by a Gaussian

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

I am computing the diffraction pattern of some specific grating. I end up with the following integral

$$I = \int dx\, J_m(x)e^{-ax^2}e^{-ikx}$$

which is the Fourier transform of the Bessel function of the first kind $J_m$, times a gaussian. I searched the literature and the tables of integrals involving Bessel functions, but I cannot find anything satisfying. The closest formula I found was in this article [arXiv:1310.8269](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8269) **[math-ph]** where the authors deal with the integral $I_{mn} = \int dx\, e^{−ax^2}e^{-ikx}x^{n+1/2}J_{m+1/2}(x)$, with $m$ and $n$ non negative integers. Perhaps there is a way to adapt their result to my integral.

Does anyone have some ideas about this?

Comment: There is nothing really novel in the article, it just applies known definitions and the formula is not really helpful at the end. You can just apply the same approach to your integral if you are satisfied with a series solution in non-elementary functions.

Comment: Could you also say what you need the integral for? For example depending on context an asymptotic answer may suffice.

Comment: I agree, this article is not so helpful.  Basically I am considering the diffraction of a plane wave on a phase and amplitude grating. The phase imposed by the grating is $\phi(x,y) = y \sin(x)$ and the amplitude transmitted is a gaussian $\exp(-a(x^2+y^2))$ in both dimensions. I used the Jacobi-Anger identity to decompose the phase term with Bessel functions, which is the reason why I have a Bessel function in the integral. The integral on x is easy to compute, but I'm left with the second integral that this question is about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that specific integral, but it would not surprise me if there was no pleasant way to write the result in closed form.  The expression you wrote *is* a function of $k$, so from a certain perspective it is what it is, and you can (numerically) evaluate it for various inputs if you'd like.

On the other hand, this is not so satisfying.  However, note that the integrand is exponentially suppressed outside the region $[-1/a,1/a]$.  If we are willing to assume that $a\gg 1$, then the only appreciable contribution is from a neighborhood of $x=0$.  The lowest order term is

$$J_m(x) \simeq x^n \frac{2^{-n}}{\Gamma(n+1)}$$

so we find

$$I_m \simeq \frac{2^{-m}}{m!} \int x^m e^{-ax^2}e^{ikx} \ dx= \frac{2^{-m}}{m! i^m} \frac{d^m}{dk^m} \int e^{-ax^2} e^{ikx} \ dx$$

which can be evaluated without too much trouble.  Higher order terms can be added to the expansion of $J_m(x)$ if you want more accuracy.

Comment: This is indeed a nice idea. Your proposition seems to give a relevant result: we were expecting Hermite polynomials to show up. However I am still curious about the general case where $x$ can have any value.